# How to set HttpOnly and Secure "lang" Sitecore cookie?

Tags: cookies, sitecore, httponly

Anyone, how to set HttpOnly and Secure flag of "lang" Sitecore cookie?
I've tried to set via processor pipeline as the following code

```
public class CookiesFlagResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
        if (current != null)
        {
            SiteContext context = Context.Site;
            string cookieKey = context.GetCookieKey("lang");
            HttpCookie cookie = current.Request.Cookies[cookieKey];
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                if (cookie.HttpOnly == false || cookie.Secure == false)
                {
                    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    cookie.Secure = true;
                    current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Patch configuration

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
        <pipelines>
            <httpRequestBegin>
                <processor type="Website.Custom.Pipelines.CookiesFlagResolver, Website" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
            </httpRequestBegin>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I have checked that the code is being hit correctly when i debug it.
Unfortunately the "lang" cookie in browser still disabled.

Comment: I agree that it's a good practice to set HttpOnly and Secure wherever it's possible. But what's the driving you to change this particular cookie? It just contains a preferred language, so there can be no or little harm having it exposed to JavaScript and sent in clear text. Also, if there are any javascript files provided by Sitecore or 3rd party module using this cookie, they won't be able to grab its value if you change it to HttpOnly.